# No Such Method Error exception thrown while using OK Http 3 with IPinfo?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies

I'm running the Java client library from [IP Info](https://github.com/ipinfo/java). When I try to executing the code:

```
IPinfo ipInfo = new IPinfo.Builder().setToken(apiKey).build();
IPResponse response = ipInfo.lookupIP(ipAddress);
```

I get a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: okhttp3.Response.close()V` exception.

I tried explicitly changing the version of [OK Http 3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp) from `5.0.0-alpha.2` to `5.0.0-alpha.1` to `4.9.0` (tried many other versions too) but they all yield the same error.

What is causing this error? Which version should I use to gain access to the said method?

My POM file has the following dependencies:

```
<dependencies>

<dependency>
 <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
 <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
 <version>8.40.14</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
 <groupId>co.ipdata.client</groupId>
 <artifactId>ipdata-java-client</artifactId>
 <version>0.2.0</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
 <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
 <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
 <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
 <groupId>io.ipinfo</groupId>
 <artifactId>ipinfo-api</artifactId>
 <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
 <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
 <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
 <version>4.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**UPDATE:**

Perhaps more intriguing, I noticed that when I open the said line with error in Eclipse

```
at io.ipinfo.api.request.IPRequest.handle(IPRequest.java:34)
```

It points to Line 34 in `io.ipinfo.api.request;` but there's absolutely no code on that line at all. The line simply contains the end of a curly brackets. See screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for all the suggestions and input! I finally found the answer myself..

It turns out that this project dependent on a different project which included the following maven dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit</groupId>
        <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
        <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

I deleted those Maven dependencies and now everything works as expected.